# How to root a samsung galaxy S3 lite(Samsung S6790)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s, samsung, kingo

How do I root a Samsung Galaxy S3 Lite(Samsung S6790).

I have tried using **towelroot v3** which returns

```
This phone is currently unsupported
```

and **framaroot** which also returns

```
Your device seems not vulnerable to exploit included in Framaroot
```

This led me to try using KingoRoot which ran for like 15mins and restarted my device. After I reconnected my device, on the menu it still had the option **root** which confirmed that the phone had not been rooted

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that KingoRoot did not root your device? It is reported as *working* for the Samsung Galaxy S3 Lite. Please verify with a [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) if you have root.

Another known method for that device is [DF ROOT (direct download)](http://s03.droidfame.zip.net/DF-ROOT.apk). This app may be in Portuguese, so if it is, here are the instructions in English:

1. Open DF-ROOT.
2. Go to "Fazer Root."
3. Choose "Root."
4. Now go to "Batal" and close the application.
5. Open SuperSU, it will ask to update the binary SU, select "Continuar."
6. Select the "Normal" option and then "OK."

Both were reported working in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2779754).

Answer (score 0):

Download iRoot to your PC, supports alot of devices. Make sure you have the latest Samsung USb drivers for mobile devices. Enable USB debugging on target device, high quality usb cable.Connect device to PC, run iRoot, wait for iRoot todetact your device and finally click Root, wait for a couple os seconds and device is rooted!